# ANT build throwing errors in WSDL generated file

Tags: java, web-services, ant, wsdl, websphere

I am using ANT to build my project. And it seems to be throwing the following errors in the files which were autogenerated from WSDL.

```
[javac] C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\BH\CPEr16Portal\source\com\ibm\cpe\bhwebservices\mdm\CPE6SOAP_HTTP_BindingStub.java:316: setUse(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enum.Use) in com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.description.OperationDesc cannot be applied to (com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Use)
[javac]         _createUpdateContactPersonOperation0.setUse(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Use.LITERAL);
[javac]                                             ^
[javac] C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\BH\CPEr16Portal\source\com\ibm\cpe\bhwebservices\mdm\CPE6SOAP_HTTP_BindingStub.java:317: setStyle(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enum.Style) in com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.description.OperationDesc cannot be applied to (com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Style)
[javac]         _createUpdateContactPersonOperation0.setStyle(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Style.DOCUMENT);
[javac]                                             ^
[javac] C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\BH\CPEr16Portal\source\com\ibm\cpe\bhwebservices\mdm\CPE6SOAP_HTTP_BindingStub.java:331: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable SEND_TYPE_ATTR_PROPERTY
[javac] location: class com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants
[javac]             mc.setProperty(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.SEND_TYPE_ATTR_PROPERTY, Boolean.FALSE);
[javac]                                                               ^
[javac] C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\BH\CPEr16Portal\source\com\ibm\cpe\bhwebservices\mdm\CPE6SOAP_HTTP_BindingStub.java:332: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable ENGINE_DO_MULTI_REFS_PROPERTY
[javac] location: class com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants
[javac]             mc.setProperty(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.ENGINE_DO_MULTI_REFS_PROPERTY, Boolean.FALSE);
[javac]                                                               ^
[javac] C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\BH\CPEr16Portal\source\com\ibm\cpe\bhwebservices\mdm\CPE6SOAP_HTTP_ServiceInformation.java:58: setStyle(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enum.Style) in com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.description.OperationDesc cannot be applied to (com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Style)
[javac]         createUpdateContactPerson0Op.setStyle(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Style.DOCUMENT);
[javac]                                     ^
[javac] Note: * uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 5 errors
```

Clearly when the error shows cannot find symbol it means that it can not find the corresponding java class.. But however These do not throw errors in RAD. And the necessary java file WAS6.1 thinclient.jar is present in the build path. So I am confused as to why the build is failing?

Can someone please guide me if I am missing something and if anything needs to be added in the ANT build file to get it to build correctly.

Regards
Snehan Solomon

Comment: You might try running `ant` in debug mode (via `ant -debug INSERT_TARGET_HERE` and see if that helps.  Additionally, take a close look at the error messages.  `setUse(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enum.Use)` doesn't match up with `(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Use)`  Note the different package names.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike, but I dont understand why RAD is not throwing that error during automatic build?? and its thrown only during ANT Build.

Comment: Probably because RAD has a different classpath value than what Ant has.

Comment: @Mike.. I did a little more digging around and this is what I found http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454435 It looks like the enum was changed to enumtupe java 1.5 onwards. I am currently using java 1.5,And in my code I am referencing the correct package `_createUpdateContactPersonOperation0.setUse(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Use.LITERAL);`
 and as you suggested I checked the class paths too and all the jars that I added are being picked up by ANT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some older version of jars in the ANT build path that were causing the build the fail, removing them fixed the issue,

Thanks Mike.

Regards
Snehan Solomon